# Lock Excel Columns by Date

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I'm trying to create a simple code for locking cell columns based on the date. I have dates (every Friday) setup from Cells C1 to BA1. The code I'm using is as follows and seems to be locking everything or it gives me an type-mismatch error.

```
Private Sub worksheet_selectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Range("C1:BA1").Value < Date Then
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="1234"
ElseIf Range("C1:BA1").Value > Date Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="1234"
    ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!
-D

Comment: To start with, I would use `Worksheet_Change` rather than `worksheet_selectionChange`. Then I would loop the columns in the `UsedRange`.

Comment: Wont you need to check each cell in C1 to BA1 not the complete range?  Or use a `countif>0` rather than that way?

Comment: Patrick, I'll give that a shot. I'm not great with programming so I'll look up how to use the usedRange and loops.

Comment: Nathan I'm not sure I understand. Isn't countif just counting cells? Does it take dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Protect` and `Unprotect` act on the sheet, not on the range. You do need to unlock the sheet, but then you need to set the `Range.Locked` property to true/false, before re-locking it. Also this requires a loop, you cannot act on the full range at once to achieve this result.

I would recommend putting this in `Workbook_Open`, so it only runs once, unless you are changing the dates; then is should go in `Worksheet_Change`.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim col As Range

    'Set the correct sheet name here:
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

        .Unprotect "1234"

        For Each col In .UsedRange.Columns

            col.EntireColumn.Locked = col.Range("A1").Value < Date

        Next col

        .Protect "1234"

        .EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Tried to use this code but doesn't seem to do anything. I'll tinker with it and see if I'm missing something but so far it just lets me do whatever I want to any of the columns rather than locking them from being edited.

Comment: `col.EntireColumn.Locked = col.Range("A1").Value < Date` is an excellent way of setting this!

Comment: This code is in the `Workbook_Open` procedure, it would go in the `Workbook` module and only run when the workbook opens. If you want it to run on selection change, then take the code from this sub and put it in your `Worksheet_SelectionChange` procedure.

Comment: Yous should also change Active sheet to be fully qualified, I will update my answer with this.

Comment: I am not 100% but will this be incorrect `col.EntireColumn.Locked = col.Range("A1").Value < Date` as the contents of the cell A1 are not actually checked if they are a date or not, so `0<date` is also true.   I would recommend some date checking before hand perhaps/

Comment: Based on the OP's requirements, I think it is safe to assume that there are dates in row 1. I agree that it might be a good idea to do *something* to handle non-date values explicitly, but I don't want to make assumptions about what the rest of the sheet has in it. The OP can take this code and modify to fit the rest of their use case.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. It might be helpful if I gave some more info. So the top row is dates. Each representing a column where someone will be initialing that they have completed work. The rest of the rows are work tasks that they are affirming have been complete so, Row 1 will be a list of dates (every friday till the end of the year, manually entered.) the first column represents the work they are completing. I want these columns to be locked after the date in Row one has passed. This way I can show who hasn't done the work. Hope that helps and thanks again everyone!

Comment: Based on that additional info, you should definitely put this in the Workbook_Open procedure. It will run once, each time the file is opened and ensure that the appropriate columns are locked even if there has not yet been a selection or input change on the sheet.

Comment: So just an update. Still having issues. I'm using the code suggested by Valon Miller but I'm getting an error on the following line `col.EntireColumn.Locked = col.Range("C1").Value < Date` the error is "Run-time error Application-defined or object-defined error". not sure why it's triggering.

Comment: `col.Range("C1")` is not valid in this context since each `col` is a single column, `col.Range("C1")` would be the third column in `col`, which doesn't exist. It should be `col.Range("A1")` where `"A1"` is a relative reference of type `[A1]` (versus `[R1C1]`) within the context of `col`.